# Changing the location of a search bar in an embedded navigation controller xcode

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

So currently my app looks like this:

[image: test]

[image: test]

I don't like the blank space at the top of the table view controller, or how the search bar disappears when you scroll down the list. I was wondering if it was possible to move the search bar onto that space at the top for the table view controller, so that it doesn't look empty and the search bar is always at the top of the screen.

Comment: It's not really blank space. It's just an empty navigation bar. Either set the view controller's title or don't use a navigation controller.

Comment: If I don't use the navigation controller, how can I go back after loading another view?

Comment: You can't so that's not an option. Set the `title` property of your view controllers so the space isn't wasted.

Comment: I feel like the space is wasted even with a title, which is the point of me asking the question to begin with

Comment: Put the search bar in the navigation bar instead of in the table view.